# Let Sn be the amount of n-permutations, set up a recurrence relation for the sequence $S_{0}, S_{1}, S_{2},.... S_{n},...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations, recurrence-relations

A)
Set up a recurrence relation for the sequence $S_{0}, S_{1}, S_{2},... S_{n},...$

B)
What are the boundary values for this sequence?

My own answer for A was $$S_{n+1}=(n+1)S_{n}$$
Since $n$ things can be done in n! ways = $S_n$

Now $n+1$ can be done in $S_n$ and the remaining element has $n+1$ positions and thus $(n+1)S_{n}$

For example for $n=7$ you get $7!$ and for $n=8$ you get $7!*8=8!$

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: The starting value would be $S_0$ or $S_1$ depending on whether you want $S_0$ defined.  Whichever you do, you can count that one by hand to get it.